# Linq join problem

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Have the following:

```
class Hal
{
    public int zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    ...
}

List<Hal> data;
Dictionary<int, List<int>> zipList;
```

zipList 
- key is "zip" 
- value is a collection of related "zip"

Want to select all "Hal" objects with "zip" from ziplist "key" AND all related "zip" from ziplist "value".

How on earth do I do this in c# linq?

Comment: It doesn't have /my/ zip code, does it? ha ha

Comment: Your class makes me say: _"I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."_ :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you mean every `Hal` in `data` where the `zip` is either in the key or the value of `zipList`? I'd probably use:

```
var zips = new HashSet<int>(zipList.Keys
                                   .Concat(zipList.Values.SelectMany(x => x));
var hals = data.Where(x => zips.Contains(x.zip));
```

To explain:

- `zipList.Values.SelectMany(x => x)` will just create a flattened view of all the values
- That's concatenated with the keys within the dictionary
- I'm creating a `HashSet<int>` from that for simplicity and efficiency of checking in the `Where` clause in a moment; alternatively a join would do this for us, but it feels simpler not to join when we're really only interested in one side
- The `Where` clause just filters the list of `Hal` objects to those with a required `zip`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a list of `Hal`s with a zip contained in the dictionary, with the related Hal's as defined by the list of zips in the dictionary value.

```
var RelatedZips = from KeyValue in zipList
                  join halData in data on KeyValue.Key equals halData.zip
                  select new
                  {
                      ZipData = halData,
                      RelatedZipData = KeyValue.Value.Select(RelatedZipIndex =>
                          data.SingleOrDefault(d => d.zip == RelatedZipIndex))
                                    .Where(z => z != null)
                  };
```

Note: Code not typed in an IDE, and untested!

Comment: That expression should give you an anonymous type with 2 members, ZipData, which is the Hal, and RelatedZipData, which is a list of the related Hals (as defined by your dictionary). If you want a single list of Hal then i've not understood what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.Join(
    zipList,
    hal => hal.zip,
    zlKvp => zlKvp.Key,
    (hal, zlKvp) => new {hal,zlKvp} //hal and KeyValuePair from zipList
);
```